# Navigation between views

Tags: iphone, cocoa-touch, uinavigationcontroller

I have app with UITabBarController. First tab has UINavigationController and it is UITableViewController. I mean I have tabs at the bottom and in first tab I have a table with possibility to navigate to other views. After touching one of cells I call view with MKMapView

```
if([indexPath section] == 3){
    LocationDetailViewController *dvController = [[LocationDetailViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"LocationDetailView" bundle:[NSBundle mainBundle]];
    dvController.locationGPS = self.locationGPS;
    [self.navigationController pushViewController:dvController animated:YES];
```

LocationDetailViewController is defined like

```
@interface LocationDetailViewController : UIViewController <MKMapViewDelegate>
```

in it I have a toolbar with button with action:

```
- (void)myCurrentAddress:(id)sender {
AddressDetailViewController *dvController = [[AddressDetailViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"AddressDetailView" bundle:[NSBundle mainBundle]];
[self.navigationController pushViewController:dvController animated:YES]; }
```

AddressDetailViewController is defined like:

```
@interface AddressDetailViewController : UIViewController
```

When I try to use code:

```
- (void)myBackAction {
[self.navigationController popViewControllerAnimated:YES]; }
```

it doesn't do anything. Debugger stops on this line - and then continues with no warnings or errors - but no changes on screen. If i remove my own back button and standard back button will be generated it will navigate back NavigationBar but not the view.
Also if I navigate to AddressDetailViewController from another tableviewcontroller class then eveyrhing is ok, where you should look into to find out the problem? please help ))

Answer (score 0):

stupid me i had 
`- (void)viewWillDisappear:(BOOL)animated {
    [self.navigationController popViewControllerAnimated:NO];`

in LocationDetailViewController - after removing it everything is ok, sorry )